# How to config rootScope to set up routing address

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, rootscope

When loading a routing address into the routeProvider in .config stage, I want to simultaneously setup the route addresses under `$rootScope`, so that all the other services can access the routing correctly.

For example, like this:

```
$rootScope.jsModules='js/modules/';
    $rootScope.appModule={
        addressbookHomeModule: {
            mName:'homeController',
            route: 'addressbook-home/',
            template: route+'home.html',
            controller: route+'homeController.js',

        },
```

However, I found and researched that its not possible to config `$rootScope` at the point of .config.

If it's possible to config `$rootScope` just by attaching another object onto it, how can I do that?

If not, I wonder if there a better way and more efficient way to store the routing location string like `partials/confirmed.html` so that all the other services can access the route correctly when I only need to config the string of the routing location once instead of all around the files in all the services?

Answer (score 2):

We can use angular.constant. We can inject constants into pretty much anything (factory service provider etc) once it's created. For example:

```
Angular.module('app).constant('routes',{home:'/'})
```